# How to install Jquery plugin in eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jquery-plugins, eclipse-marketplace

Please help me,

I Am from java background , am learning "J QUERY" program lang, please help which one is the best for develop "J QUERY"programs, am using eclipse , i have problem to install "J QUERY"plugins in eclipse am also followed all seriousness, like go to - new software install - then add SVN link, and upload zip file also, but am unable to install its not working ctrl + space bar ..

please help me how to add and can you please send screen shorts for that : gmail: veeresh.koppula@gmail.com

Comment: I am sorry but stackoverflow community will not be able to help you by emailing you. Your question should be clear and specific and people will try to answer them. Also please google "how to install jquery plugin in eclipse". You should see ton of answers

Answer (score 0):

Try the Eclipse based IDE called [Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com), it can run as an [eclipse plugin](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/success_plugin.html) too.

To use it as a plugin in your current Eclipse, just use the plugin url:

```
http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install
```

Aptana is more web development oriented, give it a try.